# Python WPF DataGrid Population

Tags: python, wpf, datagrid

Environment:
SQL Server 2012, Windows 7 Ultimate, MS Visual Studio Community 2015, Python Tools for Visual Studio v2.2.3, IronPython 2.7

Trying to populate a wpf datagrid from a database with ironpython. I don't know how to setup a datasource or connect to the database and retrieve data from a table into the datagrid. All the examples I have seen are for c# but nothing for Python. I don't know how to start to get this done. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: http://www.ironpython.info/index.php?title=Accessing_SQL_Server **?** the first match in Google

Comment: Thank you for your comment.. I was looking for some examples regarding the wpf datagrid population from a database.. any other locations would be greatly appreciated.. Thanks again..